# "-moz-user-focus" doesn't work?

Tags: css, xul

I've made this sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
 xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

   <textbox id="textBox1"/>
   <textbox id="textBox2" style="-moz-user-focus: ignore;"/>
   <textbox id="textBox3"/>
</window>
```

And, at least here, the style applied to the second textbox is doing nothing. I expected it to avoid the user focus, as the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-focus) says.

Does someone experienced this?

**--edit**

To whom it may concern, the working version:

```
<window width="400" height="300"
 onload="document.getElementById('textBox2').tabIndex='-1';"
 xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

   <textbox id="textBox1"/>
   <textbox id="textBox2" onmousedown="return false;"/>
   <textbox id="textBox3"/>
</window>
```

Comment: Is `textbox` a new element, or did you mean `<input type="text" />` (or `<textarea>`)?

Comment: @DavidThomas This is a valid element [in XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textbox).

Comment: *...ah* (somehow I'd completely glossed over that there `xul` tag) =/ Thanks @Phrogz =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textbox itself never takes focus. Instead, XBL creates an anonymous XHTML input element inside the textbox, and this is what takes focus. You can stop the textbox taking keyboard focus by setting its tab index to -1, and mouse focus by preventing the default action of mousedown events.

Another approach is to set the textbox to disabled or readonly, depending on why you don't want the textbox to be focused.

Comment: Thanks! Still, I'll let the bug report there, as I think the -moz-focus should work as well, and should prevent both keyboard and mouse focus.

Comment: @Neil "forgot" to mention the source of his text:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-focus?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F-moz-user-focus

Comment: @FacundoColombier Actually if you check the revision history of that page you'll see that my answer predates it and was copied there.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627691